# Failure to write to texture as GL_R32UI using imageStore

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-4

I have a 3D texture with an internal format of `GL_R32UI`, writing to it works fine as long as I pretend its a floating point texture.

That is if I bind it as

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform image3D Voxels;
```

And write to it with

```
imageStore(Voxels, coord.xyz, vec4(1));
```

Everything works exactly as expected.
However trying to bind it while specifying the correct type as

```
layout(r32ui, binding = 0) uniform uimage3D Voxels;
```

and writing to its with

```
imageStore(Voxels, coord.zxy, uvec4(1));
```

doesn't seem to work, that is, nothing gets written to the texture. I'd like to get this work correctly so that I can then use the `imageAtomic` operations.  Anyone have any idea what could be going on?

Comment: If you just want to clear the texture to a value, then clear the texture to a value. Also, how do you detect that "nothing gets written to the texture"? Are you using the proper barriers after writing to the texture?

Comment: I don't want to clear the texture to a value. I want to be able to write whichever value I want wherever I want. For debugging I normally just look at a slice-wise view of the texture.

Comment: Right, but *how* do you look at it? Are you using the proper memory barriers to ensure that the data written has been written before you try to read it?

Comment: Well tossing a `glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS)` between writing and rendering doesn't change anything, if that answers your question.

Comment: Ah, having written to the texture as though it were an unsigned integer texture (which it is), it can no longer be displayed with the same shader code.  That is, `sampler3D` had to be changed to `isampler3D` in the display code.  Which makes sense, but its strange that it worked at all when treated as a floating point texture, will unfortunately make my display code much less general purpose.  Thanks for the help.